# HTTP cache is not working in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, http, caching, cache-control

As per Symfony docs I made changes in app.php like this to use gateway cache.

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

However when I do page request even though content is stale it is not hitting my controller. This is the header.

```
Age 438
Cache-Control   max-age=1440042297, must-revalidate, public, s-maxage=1440042297
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 1097
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date Thu, 20 Aug 2015 03:52:10 GMT
Expires Thu, 20 Aug 2015 03:44:57 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Vary Accept-Encoding
x-content-digest en03aa34b1bc631613037479d58277f71c67bb577b2549a80ad92e7009eb733736
```

and this is my controller code.

```
$response = new Response;
$response->setMaxAge($searchResult->getValidUntil()->getTimestamp())
         ->setSharedMaxAge($searchResult->getValidUntil()->getTimestamp())
         ->setExpires($searchResult->getValidUntil())
         ->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
```

As you can see expiration date is passed but new content was not requested. Is there anything else that I need to do.

Comment: And if you remove the `$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);` your controller is get a hit?

Comment: Yes it does if I remove that line.